# Site looks great on iOS8 and Android but has bad scale/viewport on iOS7 and lower

Tags: ipad, ios7, viewport, frontend

I have created a web-page. It's works well on PC and mobile(all Android and iOS8). But on iOS 7 (tested iPad Mini) initial scale is wrong. How it's must be:[image: iOS8]

But on iPad Mini and iOS7 I have got this:
[image: iPad Mini]:
[image: iOS7 Simulator]

This site available on **http://test15.norelport.org**. I use this viewport params:

```
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, initial-scale=0"/>
</head>
```

Do you know how to fix it? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I can create simple example on jsfiddle for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding viewport buggyfill from here [**Viewport Units Buggyfill**](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill).

It's a bug of iOS7 and lower.